# unable to press the view when I passed callback as props to TouchableHighlight component

Tags: react-native

I am passing callback to `<TouchableHighlight>` component onPress method to display alert, but it  is not working. 
But when I pass alert('item pressed') directly to onPress() method it works.

I am using simple example of `<ScrollList>` from react-native.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  ListView,
  SectionList,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import ScrollableTabView, { ScrollableTabBar, } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import navStyles from './../styles'
import dataFields from './../Constants/constants'
import JsonInputFeedComponent from './../../Components/JsonInputFeedComponent'
import Divider from './../../Components/Divider'
import ScreenMenuObject from './../Screens'
import { iconsMap } from './../../appIcons'

import PlanYourDay from './PlanYourDay'
import Questionnaire from './Questionnaire'
import NewProfilePage from './NewProfilePage'

import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')

 const datasource=[ {data: [ {name: 'PAST MEDICAL CONDITIONS' }, {name: 'PAST VACCINATONS' }, {name: 'PAST TESTS'}, 
 {name: 'CURRENT GENERAL MEDICAL CONDITIONS'}, {name: 'MEN ONLY MEDICAL CONDITIONS'},{ name: 'WOMEN ONLY MEDICAL CONDITIONS' }],
 key:'ADDITIONAL QUESTIONNAIRE'}, ]

export default class ProfilePage extends Component {
  static navigatorButtons = {
    leftButtons: [],
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onFieldChange = this.onFieldChange.bind(this)

    this.renderModal = this.renderModal.bind(this)

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigator.setButtons({
      leftButtons: [{ id: 'sideMenu', icon: iconsMap['menu'] }],
    });
  }



  renderModal(){
    alert('list item clicked')
  }




  render() {
    const data = dataFields.profilePage
    return (
       <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ScrollableTabView
        initialPage={0}
        renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
      >

        <ScrollView tabLabel="FLAT LIST" >

            <SectionList
              renderItem={({ item }) => 
               (  <View>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.renderModal}><Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
                  </View>
                 )
               }
              renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text style={styles.itemHeader}>{section.key}</Text>}
              sections={datasource}
             keyExtractor={(item)=>item.name}
            />

        </ScrollView>
        </ScrollableTabView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabView: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
  },
  card: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
    margin: 5,
    padding: 15,
    shadowColor: '#ccc',
    shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2, },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 3,
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    color: 'blue'
  },
   headerText: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color:'blue',
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    fontSize:10,
    padding: 0,
    borderColor:'blue',
    borderWidth:2
  },
  content: {
    height:'100%',
    padding: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  itemHeader: {
    fontSize:15,
    padding: 5,
    color:'blue',
  },
  itemText:{
    fontSize:15,
    color:'black',
    padding:10,
    marginLeft:width *0.15,
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us with all the code ( renderModal method ) please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this**:

```
onPress={()=>this.renderModal}
```

**to** :

```
onPress={()=>this.renderModal()}
```

Implement renderModal function:

```
renderModal() {
  alert("On Press");
}
```

This will work fine.

Comment: It worked!!! why are we calling it, where as it will be called onPress event occurs?

Comment: you haven't call it as function renderModal.